# Java Google Sheets API example with autoResizeDimensionsRequest

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm wondering how to use autoResizeDimensions in order to set the columns to auto resize. The following

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

        AutoResizeDimensionsRequest autoResizeDimensions = new AutoResizeDimensionsRequest();
        requests.add(new Request()
                .setAutoResizeDimensions(autoResizeDimensions));
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
                .setRequests(requests);
        SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
                .execute();
```

returns the following error message

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid requests[1].autoResizeDimensions: Only the COLUMNS dimension is supported",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid requests[1].autoResizeDimensions: Only the COLUMNS dimension is supported",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

I'm also interested in setting a specific width for a column. I haven't found any examples using java. If anyone has come across one or know how would love to no about it.

Additionally I've added setDimensions to that code

```
DimensionRange dimensions = new DimensionRange().setDimension("A1:C6");
```

with the setAutoResizeDimensions

```
requests.add(new Request()
                .setAutoResizeDimensions(autoResizeDimensions
                        .setDimensions(dimensions)));
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[3].auto_resize_dimensions.dimensions.dimension' (TYPE_ENUM), \"A1:C6\"",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[3].auto_resize_dimensions.dimensions.dimension' (TYPE_ENUM), \"A1:C6\"",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

Thanks
Conteh

Comment: What about the above doesn't work?

Comment: @SamBerlin,  I've made some edits. Hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failures all stem from the same reason: [`AutoResizeDimensionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AutoResizeDimensionsRequest) is not setup properly.

You need to supply a valid [`DimensionRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#DimensionRange) into the request's `dimensions` field in order for the request to know which dimensions to resize.  The documentation for DimensionRange describes it's purpose: `A range along a single dimension on a sheet. All indexes are zero-based. Indexes are half open: the start index is inclusive and the end index is exclusive. Missing indexes indicate the range is unbounded on that side.`

The first error (`"Invalid requests[1].autoResizeDimensions: Only the COLUMNS dimension is supported"`) is because the request is using the default `DimensionRange`, which means the `DimensionRange.dimension` field is using its default value of `DIMENSION_UNSPECIFIED`. The field is an enum of type [`Dimension`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AutoResizeDimensionsRequest) whose default value is `DIMENSION_UNSPECIFIED`.  So the error message is saying, "Only COLUMNS is supported" and is implicitly saying, "... but you supplied DIMENSION_UNSPECIFIED or ROWS".

The second error (`"Invalid value at 'requests[3].auto_resize_dimensions.dimensions.dimension' (TYPE_ENUM), \"A1:C6\""`) is because you wrote an A1 range into the `dimension` field.  The error message is saying: "You gave me an invalid value.  I am an enum, but you gave me A1:C6, and that isn't a valid enum."

The valid values for `dimension` are `ROWS` or `COLUMNS` (and `AutoResizeDimensionRequest` requires that you specify `COLUMNS`). In addition, you'll want to specify the `sheetId` (the ID of the sheet whose columns you want to resize) and a `startIndex` and `endIndex` of which columns you want to resize.

For example, if you wanted to automatically resize rows 0 and 1, you would use:

    `AutoResizeDimensionsRequest autoResizeDimensions = new AutoResizeDimensionsRequest();
    DimensionRange dimensions = new DimensionRange().setDimension("COLUMNS").setStartIndex(0).setEndIndex(2);
    autoResizeDimensions.setDimensions(dimensions);`

(`endIndex` is `2` because end indexes are exclusive, whereas start indexes are inclusive.)

Comment: You can see a REST recipe of auto-resizing a column here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/rowcolumn#automatically_resize_a_column